# R how to do summation over matrix division by vector of rows

Tags: r

In R I want to calculate for the following:

[image]

This is the way I have it

```
for (i in 1:dim(x)[1] ) {
  for (j in 1:dim(x)[2] ) {
      omega_2new[i] = sum((X[,j]-munew)^2/sigma_2new[j])
  }
}
omega_2new = omega_2new/dim(x)[2]
```

what's the fastest way to do it in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With @Zbynek's data, but avoiding R loops and summing the rows (which I believe is required):

```
1/ncol(M)*colSums(t((M-munew)^2)/sigma_2new)
```

Comment: The results of my and your solution do not match. I am not sure about `t((M-munew)^2)/sigma_2new` bit.

Comment: @Zbynek I'm aware of that and I think your result is wrong. You sum the columns, but the equation in the question sums the rows.

Comment: I think in original code the columns are summed: `for (j in 1:dim(x)[2] ) {
      omega_2new[i] = sum((X[,j]-munew)^2/sigma_2new[j])
  }`

Comment: I don't know if this code is correct. The equation at the top of the question sums the rows.

Comment: The original code doesn't work, so I would look at the equation instead. Roland's code does what the equation asks for.

Answer (score 1):

First I create some sample data

```
M <- matrix(runif(100), nrow=10)

sigma_2new <- runif(10)

munew <- mean(M)
```

And then use `sapply` over the range of columns

```
omega_2new <- sapply(1:nrow(M), function(x) sum((M[x,]-munew)^2/sigma_2new[x]))
omega_2new
 [1] 1.4127063 3.9928844 1.3996303 1.2290480 1.4367367 4.9893873 0.9401457 0.6567372 4.5156849 1.0743495
```